# How to do SUM(MAX( ) + MAX( ))?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a proper way to do `SUM(MAX() + MAX())`?

Here's what I've been trying to do

```
SELECT 
  SUM(MAX(account.BALANCE1) + MAX(account.BALANCE2)) AS TOTALBALANCE
FROM
  account
      JOIN
  transaction t ON account.PRIMARYKEY = t.ACCOUNTKEY
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
          1
      FROM
          transaction a
      WHERE
          a.ACCOUNTKEY = t.ACCOUNTKEY
              AND a.TYPE = 'PAYMENT')
HAVING TOTALBALANCE > 0
```

It reads:

> Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have any `GROUP BY` clause specified,

`MAX(account.BALANCE1) + MAX(account.BALANCE2)`

should aready suffice your needs.

Comment: I think I got you the wrong question sir.. Let me edit it.. Any how, I'll be using this as a sub query..

Comment: i was going to recommend subquery, but i think john's answer is better...seems like the right answer to me